# What is better in mysql- Multiple tables with less no. of records or one table with large no. of records

Tags: mysql

I have a table anonymous with three column **(Title,Tough,Id)** in which only eight different values of tough can be entered.Now I want to know is their any need to make 8 different tables for each value of tough in my database for fast SQL querying.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Is this a table that holds types, or is this a table that has items that have types?  (And, either way, my answer is: Stick with one table.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I should do is the following (assuming Type is a `VARCHAR`)

Create one new table having two columns **(typeId, type)**. Then lay a reference to your anonymous table. This reduces your data storage, you only have to capture the 8 values once. Then you only use number to reference to these 8 values.

I don't know for sure if this will boost your query performances but this surely will make your database contain a lot less of redundant data.

Comment: @AnkitGautam don't forget to mark as answer if this helped you out :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table `Types` with columns `type_id` and `type_name`, than create another table with columns `anonymous_id`, `title`, and `type_id`.

In the second table, `type_id` would be a foreign key linking to the primary key (type_id) of table `Types`.

That way your tables are optimized and contain less duplicate data, and you can allow only those types that are already in the database, so much more scalable.

Comment: There's no need to create 8 tables, but it's best to create 1 extra table containing type_name and type_id. Then in your first column, you can add FK_type and reference the type_id in the second column.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you continue to use a single table for it, and see how if works. It will simplify your application structure and not hinder your sight of different problems.

However, if you're on a deadline, then you should consider your application structure and how the index will grow. If it's too much pain to change your application, then you should redo it quickly until it grows into unresolvable problem.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should try to normalise your data structures, and worry about performance once measurement has shown you need to.

```
CREATE TABLE `Anonymous` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tough_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `idxTough` (`tough_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Tough` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `Tough` (`name`) VALUES ('ToughA'), ('ToughB'), ('ToughC'), ('ToughD');

INSERT INTO `Anonymous` (`title`, `tough_id`) VALUES
    ('Anon with tough A', 1),
    ('Anon with tough B', 2),
    ('Anon with tough C', 3),
    ('Anon with tough D', 4)
;
```